# How to control how Py3k deals with escaped characters in bytes and unicode

Tags: python-3.x

I'm working with python 3.2, and the way it handles escaped characters seems almost... non deterministic.  The only way I can get them to actually work as a newline (rather than as an escape) is to print them.  Here's what the behavior looks like:

```
>>> a = 'a\nb'
>>> a
'a\nb'
>>> a.encode('ascii')
b'a\nb'
>>> print(a)
a
b
>>> print(a.encode('ascii'))
b'a\nb'
>>> print(str(a.encode('ascii')))
b'a\nb'
```

I'm sure that the intricacies of this are documented somewhere, I just can't find it. Maybe there's a bytes -> string method somewhere that is the opposite of encode (decode?).

Answer (score 5):

It is perfectly deterministic and simple. You need to be aware of the differences between bytes and unicode strings though. Read [Pragmatic Unicode](http://bit.ly/unipain) by Ned Batchelder.

`a` refers to a unicode string composed to three characters, so `a` evaluates to that and the Python REPL tries to `print()` it -- the first step is converting it to a `str` (which is just `return self` for strings). The resulting string is converted into bytes according to the encoding associated with stdout (e.g. your terminal), and sends these bytes there. Your terminal interprets the bytes it receives according to the encoding it uses.

`a.encode('ascii')` explicitly converts the unicode into a byte sequence, using the ASCII encoding. The result of that is a bytes object, and that result is `print`'d by the Python REPL. Again, the first step is converting it to a string -- because bytes are not strings, and implicit conversions between the two are very harmful as Python 2 encoding/decoding errors proves, you only get what `repr` also gives you: A string which is equivalent to a bytes literal in Python source code. This string is then printed as before, same difference.

In `>>> print(a)`, you call `print` yourself with the same consequences as above, and the result of `print` is `None` so the Python REPL does not print it. Same for `>>> print(a.encode('ascii'))` and `>>> print(str(a.encode('ascii')))`, you just trigger the printing explicitly and do the `str` conversion beforehand instead of implicitly.

There is indeed an inverse of `str.encode`, it's indeed called `decode` and is a method of `bytes` objects. So `some_str.encode(E).decode(E)` can be a no-op. It can also lose information or alter the string along the way (e.g. by replacing unknown characters), or throw an exception if you do not ask it to lose information.

If you have bytes which represent some string in some encoding, you can use them for I/O. In fact, this is the "native" way of doing I/O -- all I/O and all networking is bytes. But `print` is for strings. Instead, in the case of file I/O (including stdout), you want to open them in binary mode and use the `.write` method. For `sys.stdout` specifically, text mode is used by default, but you can access a binary version as [`sys.stdout.buffer`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/sys.html#sys.stdout). Of course, if the bytes you send were created assuming a different encoding (or not intended as text at all), you'll get gibberish.

Comment: Thanks for explaining how it works so quickly and thoroughly.